# Filing and use of function tellp()

Tags: c++, file

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream out;
    int pos;
    out.open("myfile.txt",ios::app);
    pos=out.tellp();
    cout<<pos;
    int *arr=new int[pos+5];
    cout<<"Enter a line: ";
    char str[60];
    cin.getline(str,60); 
    out<<str;
    cout<<"Data written in file"<<endl<<"position of file "<<out.tellp()<<endl;
    out.close();
    delete []arr;
}
```

Here I open a file in append mode (so there is some data in file). But at the start when I print position it shows zero, but after written data in the file it shows correct position (including the position of previous data which is in the file but not shown the correct position at line 10). How could I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode), this is expected behaviour:

> `app`: seek to the end of stream before each write
>   [...]
>   `ate`: seek to the end of stream immediately after open

You want to open the file with `ate` if you want the file to be seeked before you write anything.